# mad behaviour of my divs

Tags: html, css

I have about **3 div**, with class as  "**qcircle**" and i have defined them using css in order to appear as 3 circles. and they are given " **display:inline-block**;" so that i would get them **horizontaly arrainged in a line**.
  **i want to write some thing inside these 3 divs**,so i **used a paragraph tag**.
but when i did that in the first cirlce, **the whole cirlce including given content comes down and other 2 cirlces stay where they are**..
I have no idea why this is happening can some body help me with this ????
Here is my html:

```
            <div class="qcircle">
                <p> THE FIRST ONE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="qcircle">

            </div>
            <div class="qcircle">

            </div>
            <div class="qcircle">

            </div>
```

and here is my css rules

```
.circles{
text-align: center;
}
.qcircle{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: black;
display: inline-block;
}
.qcircle p{
color: blue;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

this is the codepen link
http://codepen.io/ShamZ/pen/WxRbKw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give `display: inline-block`, it automatically `vertical-align`s itself to the `baseline`. Make it `top`:

```css
.circles{
  text-align: center;
}
.qcircle{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.qcircle p{
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="qcircle">
  <p> THE FIRST ONE</p>
</div>
<div class="qcircle">

</div>
<div class="qcircle">

</div>
<div class="qcircle">

</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Another way you cold achieve the same visual result is to add `position:relative` to the `<p>` class

Comment: @Jake Really? Lemme try. Nope. That doesn't work. It's the QCircle the OP is targeting and not the P.

Comment: That's weird... it worked for me once... now I can't make it happen again... That's what I get for using chrome dev tools :P

Comment: No it was my mistake.. I read the wrong thing. `position:absolute` on the `<p>` will do it.. not `relative`. I knew I wasn't going crazy..

Comment: But can u explain a bit , coz i did'nt really understand why they are moving up by giving position:absolute; and  vertical-align: top;...

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed Sorry.. Giving `position: absolute` will remove them from the flow of the document. Giving `vertical-align: top` will make the `inline-block` elements to align vertically and not to the `baseline`, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `display: flex` on the container div

```css
.circles{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.qcircle{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-right: 4px
}

.qcircle p{
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="qcircle">
    <p> THE FIRST ONE</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="qcircle">  

  </div>
  <div class="qcircle">

  </div>
  <div class="qcircle">

  </div>
</div>
```